Downloading Imagery Tiles from Amazon S3
So....NOAA used to host post-hurricane tiles in-house where they were really easy to download using a Python script and the appropriate tile index layer. Recently, NOAA has moved those imagery repositories to an Amazon AWS S3 repository (https://noaa-eri-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) where the download using Python is not as straightforward. Basically, it doesn't work anymore. Python will attempt to open the file then write its contents to a new file on the local drive, but the new file is empty. Here's the code I am trying to use. HELP PLEASE!!!!
import os
from boto3.session import Session
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
ACCESS_KEY = '{your_access_key}'
SECRET_KEY = '{your_secret_key}'
bucket = 'noaa-eri-pds'
#
#The below is just one tile. If I can get the code to work, this will be in a loop to 
#grab them all using the index
key = '2023_Pre_Event/GC2301b_OB_N_RGB/GC2301b_OB_N_C0805830w250600n.tif' 
filename = 'GC2301b_OB_N_C0805830w250600n.tif'
localfilename = os.path.join('E:/PythonSandbox/Amazon_AWS/', filename)  # The local directory must exist.
s3.download_file(bucket, key, localfilename)
with open(localfilename, 'wb') as f:
    s3.download_fileobj(bucket, key, f)


Note that your code is unnecessarily downloading the object twice. Once when calling s3.download_file and a second time when calling s3.download_fileobj.

You don't need an S3 client to download those tiles.
The S3 bucket is available to the world, as is visible from e.g.
~/Desktop $ wget 'https://noaa-eri-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/2023_Pre_Event/GC2301b_OB_N_RGB/GC2301b_OB_N_C0805830w250600n.tif'
[...]
2024-10-29 19:59:46 (1,71 MB/s) - ‘GC2301b_OB_N_C0805830w250600n.tif’ saved [983410/983410]
$

so you can just use any HTTP client library (e.g. httpx, requests) in Python to grab them.
import httpx

with httpx.Client() as c:
   resp = c.get("https://noaa-eri-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/2023_Pre_Event/GC2301b_OB_N_RGB/GC2301b_OB_N_C0805830w250600n.tif")
   resp.raise_from_status()
   with open("GC2301b_OB_N_C0805830w250600n.tif", "wb") as outf:
       outf.write(resp.content)

(You might want to use streamed responses if you expect the content to be large.)

Interesting. I guess I missed that part when I was researching it before. The problem is...where is Python writing the downloaded file?

UPDATE: I figured it out. It saves the downloaded file in the CWD of the script. Many thanks for the help!
